Why the prohibition of idolatry doesn't stem from the Mitzvah of loving God?
The second commandment of the Ten, prohibits idolatry out of God's jealousy and harsh multi-generational punishment.
In the current era of romanticism, jealousy usually arises from deep love and affection between partners. Based on the Talmudic and later Kabbalistic depiction of the love and affection between God and Israel as His spouse, I would expect that the Torah would reflect a similar tendency, in a way that the second command would look something like the following:

"Thy shall love YHWH your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your might. As I YHWH your God am an impassioned God, thy shall have no other gods besides Me.
Thy shall not make for yourself a sculptured image, or any likeness of what is in the heavens above, or on the earth below, or in the waters under the earth..."

Why is Hashem's love for Israel not mentioned as the basis for the prohibition of idolatry either in the Ten Commandments or anywhere else?

Nice question, you are speaking to my heart. I saw in this weeks parasha that it say (paraphrased) "when you get to Israel and have all these amazing cities ready made for you, don't go inquiring about the foreign gods, don't do that to Hashem, because He finds the things they did horrible and He loves you". Was going to look into it soon. Let you know if I find anything +1

You could certainly talk about how love is connected but in terms of mitzvos they are two independent mitzvos as well

@Dude That was my other question - why the whole Matan Torah was out of fear rather than love and fun. The third question is if love is so fundamental, why isn't it mentioned in the TC altogether?

Fun? Not sure why fun is relevant. The 10 sayings are categories that include all commandments. Not every mitzvah is directly spelled out but every one of mitzvos is included. The giving of the Torah is portrayed by the moshel of a chassuna so the primary emotion is love. Fearing Gd is also another mitzvah. The mitzvos of loving and gearing G-d are intertwined as the love which compels someone to act and fear which causes someone to be afraid of being separated by bad actions.

ואהבת את ה' אלהיך - משמע שלא תמירנו בעבודת כוכבים:
https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.74a.15.1.            At least the gemara with rashi seems to mention it, but you are correct that it doesn't make the 10 commandments

Trying to answer With the help of Torah Temimah.
The mitzvah of loving G-d is derived from the verse Devarim 6:5.
In connection with this verse several different definitions of what loving G-d can be made.

On this verse Rashi says,


Fulfill His commands out of love, for one who acts out of love is not like him (is on a higher plane than one) who acts out of fear. He who serves his master out of fear, if he (the master) troubles him overmuch, leaves him and goes away (Sifrei Devarim 32:1).

Therefore, according to Rashi, mitzvah of loving G-d is an additional requirement which is fulfilled with each and every mitzvah. In this case, one cannot derive prohibition of idolatry as it can be kept simply out of fear of G-d (Devarim 6:13, Devarim 10:20), the second of which Rashi comments:

THOU SHALT FEAR THE LORD THY GOD, and serve Him and cleave to Him; and after you possess all these qualities, then you may swear by His Name.


Gemara Yoma 86a offers another definition


Abaye said: As it was taught in a baraita that it is stated: “And you shall love the Lord your God” (Deuteronomy 6:5), which means that you shall make the name of Heaven beloved. How should one do so? One should do so in that he should read Torah, and learn Mishna, and serve Torah scholars, and he should be pleasant with people in his business transactions.

This definition, as noted in the Gemara further, when violated can be viewed as desecration of the Name, but not idolatry.

One can also even follow the statement of Rambam about joint Love-fear (Mishneh Torah, Yesodei haTorah 2:1):


It is a mitzvah to love and fear this glorious and awesome God, as [Deuteronomy 6:5] states: "And you shall love God, your Lord" and, as [Deuteronomy 6:13] states: "Fear God, your Lord."

This definition is probably the closest in implying prohibition of idolatry. As Torah Temimah notes that in case of tribulations a person may say - I do not want to keep the commandments, however because of fear one will still keep them. As one see here, it's brought together with two separate verses, not one. Rambam is not even using a more suitable verse for it Devarim 11:1. Still, these are additional verses, as opposed to explicit prohibitions of idolatry in Sefer Shemos and other books of Torah. Thus, one has to conclude that one can serve idols despite love of Hashem and despite fear of Hashem. Perhaps, a good example - people responding to the miracle that Hashem did for Eliyahu on Mt. Carmel.

Rambam when formulating his eighth principle of faith, that the Torah that we have is the same as was given to Moshe by Hashem refers to gemara Sanhedin 99a


It is taught in another baraita: “Because he has despised the word of the Lord”; this is a reference to one who says the Torah did not originate from Heaven. And even if one says the entire Torah originated from Heaven except for this verse, i.e., any one verse, claiming that the Holy One, Blessed be He, did not say it but Moses himself said it on his own, this is included in the category of: “Because he has despised the word of the Lord.” And even if one says the entire Torah originated from Heaven except for this inference inferred by the Sages, or except for this a fortiori inference, or except for this verbal analogy, this is included in the category of: “Because he has despised the word of the Lord.”

While the violation here is not idolatry, it seems that it became the basis of the mitzvah of loving G-d is described in (Sefer haChinuch Mitzvah 418) (translation of R. Charles Wengrow):

The substance of the precept is that we should consider and reflect on His commandments and His handiwork, until we attain a concept of Him according to our ability, and we can then feel joy in appreciating Him, with the utmost delight.  This is obligatory, an essential love.
The language of the Midrash Sifrei Devarim 33: While it is stated and you shall love, I do not know how a man is to love the omnipresent G-d. Hence, Scripture states, Devarim 6:6 And these matters which I command you today shall be on your heart. For as a result of this you will "recognize" the One who spoke and the world came into existence. In other words, with reflection-understanding in the Torah, the love [of G-d] settles perforce in the heart. And the Sages of blessed memory said, Sifrei Devarim 32 that this love should impel a man to arouse people about love for Him - as we find in the instance of Abraham.

We believe that G-d commands and teaches entire Torah to us every day, as we formulate blessings on the Torah in the present tense. Placing on the heart the commandments is a component of love as stated in Sifrei above, so that violation of commandments is the opposite.
Thus, we have to conclude that fulfilling the mitzvah of loving G-d is contingent on contemplating and fulfilling of ALL commandments, including the multiple prohibitions of idolatry, and not the other way around. Through the Torah, with persistence and time, one gains a conception or appreciation of the Creator who gave the Torah, His immanence and influence in this world; and this must inevitably inculcate love of Him. Since only after fulfiling many commandments one can attain a level of loving G-d, it becomes clear why the mitzvah is placed at the end of the Torah and not at the very beginning.
As a side note, the Mitzvah to fear G-d Sefer haChinuch Mitzva 432, refers to fear of punishment.

+1 for effort. I have a problem with cherry-picking sources, like saying "oh, there's one source that fits what I want to relay, so let's use it". I understand that the Torah is multifaceted, but one source does not move the needle, you need to show a consistent view across many different sources.

I don't understand your "conclusion" - does it really and necessarily follow?

Please explain, why the Mitzva of loving God is stuck at the end of Moses' retelling, instead of being the 2nd commandment, as you proposed, that all other commandments follow.

@AlBerko Good points to improve the answer. Your first comment: please, show me a source speaking otherwise. On my side I will add from Rambam's discussion of Principle of faith 8, which is universally accepted. Your second comment we believe that G-d commands and teaches entire Torah to us every day, placing on the heart the commandments is a component of love; violation of commandments is the opposite. Third comment obviously, the mitzvah dependent on everything else has to be at the end. If you like I will add all these points in the answer.


"otherwise" what? The whole Torah is "otherwise". We’ve already discussed that the Matan Torah show was planned to be frightening - כפה עליהם הר כגיגית. In some commandments, God explicitly threatens Israel with horrors. Love to God is not mentioned in the first four books. Why did Moses add Love and other Mitzvos for the next generations but not the generation that received the Torah? Try to read the Torah and see if you find any support for the claim that love is necessary for observance in the Torah.



As a pragmatist, I have no idea what you said - what God puts in you every day, and how God teaches you anything. You clearly confuse deduction and induction - conclusion and assumption. You generalize therefore you assume, you use inductive logic, and the conclusion is necessarily deductive.


1.5 In the details of the Mitzva of loving God, I don’t see Rambam apprehending the contingency you're talking about: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.2.2?lang=he

3 You should be more careful with words like "conclusion" or "obviously".  As I said, the generation of Exodus who received the Torah didn't hear of it, so it is probably NOT a foundational principle. Imagine a master giving a long list of hundreds of to-dos and adding at the end, and you should do them all with love. How do you explain the Torah narrative or do you completely ignore it?

"וַיְצַוֵּנוּ יְהֹוָה לַעֲשׂוֹת אֶת־כׇּל־הַחֻקִּים הָאֵלֶּה לְיִרְאָה אֶת־יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵינוּ לְטוֹב לָנוּ כׇּל־הַיָּמִים לְחַיֹּתֵנוּ כְּהַיּוֹם הַזֶּה׃"

@AlBerko I think I may have addressed this, point 3.

It is very important to keep in mind that G-d is entirely above the concept of emotions. Use of emotional terms in reference to G-d are no different than use of physical terms in reference to G-d; that is, they are metaphorical terms. The term Kinah refers to someone insisting on his rights.
As the creator, G-d has the right to insist we worship Him and no false gods. This is independent of and prior to the commandment to love G-d. It is only once you accept the uniqueness of G-d that it makes sense not to worship false idols. If one does not accept the uniqueness of G-d, then those idols might actually have power, ch"v, and there would be no cause for jealousy if one worshiped them. This is why in the Shma (Deuteronomy 6:4-5), the commandment to love G-d comes after the commandment to recognize G-d as one, which parallels the negative commandment of worshiping false idols. (Maimonides Foundations of the Torah ch.1, 6-7)
All this being said, it is definitely true that loving G-d will prevent a person from worshiping idols. This is seen in the case where a false prophet encourages people to worship idols. The Torah says

Do not listen to the words of that prophet or to that dreamer of a dream, because Adonoy, your God, is testing you to know whether you love Adonoy, your God, wholeheartedly and with your entire beings.


Thank you. I could never understand that "אחד בלב ואחד בפה" - all our prayers are premised on the concept of God's emotions, and still we declare that God officially "above the concept of emotions".

I would correct "perceived rights", you can be jealous of a girl you have no official connection to. Now, why does worshipping precede love? I would suggest that only after you establish your love you base your right for jealousy. Contrary, if your right is premised on the creation, there can be no claim for love, as there's no commandment to love thy parents of thy king.
